# ACF repeater + group shortcode

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I've wrote a few line in order to show a restaurant menu in a page using a shortcode

```
add_shortcode ('pescato_repeater', 'pescato_repeater_fn');
  function pescato_repeater_fn() {
    if( have_rows('pescato') ) {
    $content = '<h2>Pescato del Mediterraneo<br><span id="eng">Caught of the Mediterranean</span></h2><table>';
      while( have_rows('pescato') ) { 
        the_row();
        $nome = get_sub_field('name');
        $content .= '<tr><td>' . implode("<br><span id=\"eng\">", $name) . '</span></td><td class="price">' .  get_sub_field('price') . ' €/Kg</td><tr>';
      }
    $content .= '</table>';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

the sub field *name* is a group in which there are names in italian and english, so I'm using *implode* in order to show the array.

[image: elementor preview]

The elementor preview is showing it correctly, but the page doesn't. It has worked for a while but now, if I try to refresh the page, the loading seems to be locked in a loop that never ends

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "It has worked for a while but now, if I try to refresh the page, the loading seems to be locked in a loop that never ends". Sounds like an error introduced by something else. Did you modify/add any extra feature to the site. Your shortcode callback looks good, I don't see a reason for an infinite loop there. Do you have WP_DEBUG set to true?

Comment: 'What does "the page doesn't [show it correctly]" mean? Just the "loading loop bit?